# List items in AppFolder in Google Drive Picker

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use the picker to manage files saved to the **appDataFolder** through the Google Drive API. Is this possible, or will I need to write my own ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the Google Drive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata) the 'Application Data folder' is a special folder that is only accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user, and from other apps.

Also, it is stated here that to be able to use the Application Data folder, you need to request access to this scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

There is also example code [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata#listing_files_from_the_application_data_folder) for different language on how to list files from the Application Data folder.

For the picker API, in the [Handling Google Drive Items](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#gdata) part, it is stated here that the picker interface can display a list of the currently authenticated user's Google Drive files.